# Populate CPT meta data with Contact Form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I try to populate meta fields (i'm using the add_metaboxes procedures to declare and add metadata to my custom-post-type, which is working fine) using the "Post My CF7 Form" plugin.

For this, I try to use the "Map form fields to post meta-fields". For each field, I name the custom_meta_key and give the corresponding field. However, after saving my form, the value return to custom_meta_key instead of using the given name of the meta_field : in brief, it is not saved.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong ? does this functionality only work with newly created cpt by the plugin ? Where can I find the functions permitting this population ?

THX in andvace !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.